# TortoiseSVN gives "Conflicted (maybe)" state after test merge?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am attempting a Test Merge from the trunk back into a branch to get the recent changes using the TortoiseSVN for Windows.  I get an ambiguous message that says "Conflicted (maybe)" on two of the files.  Never seen this before so I googled a little around but could not find anything on it.  Any idea what causes this unusual state and how can I get a straight answer out of it?

-- Edit 2017127 1454
Oddly enough I tried the merge and they did conflict, but there were no conflicts as far as I could tell.  The files were conflicted on one line each, but there seemed to be no changes, even no whitespace changes.  I chose one, saved, resolved the conflict and the merge completed.  Still not sure what is going on though.

Comment: maybe some difference in the line ending?

Comment: Maybe.  I did the merge and moved on though.  If I get it again I will check  and update this.